# Incorrect output. C++ primer 1.4.4

Tags: c++, visual-c++

the following program is supposed to count the number of times a user inputs a integer. example: user inputs 42 42 10 10. the program is supposed to out put : 42 occurs 2 times, 10 occurs 2 times.

the problem: the code will not output the last result for the number 10 until you input another number. i have pasted the code below. this code comes from c++ primer. 1.4.4

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // currVal is the number we're counting; we'll read new values into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;

    // read first number and ensure that we have data to process
    if (std::cin >> currVal) 
    {
        int cnt = 1;  // store the count for the current value we're processing

        while (std::cin >> val) 
        { // read the remaining numbers

            if (val == currVal)   // if the values are the same
                ++cnt;            // add 1 to cnt
            else 
            { // otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
                currVal = val;    // remember the new value
                cnt = 1;          // reset the counter
            }

        }  // while loop ends here

        // remember to print the count for the last value in the file
        std::cout << currVal <<  " occurs " << cnt << " times" << std::endl;
    } // outermost if statement ends here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using the code as it is, you need to input a non-numeric string as well as those numbers and you'll get the count without having to input a new number.

Comment: @splrs, i am very new to programming. could you provide an example of what a "non-numeric string" is ? or an example of the code needed to correct the output issue ?

Comment: Try entering 10 10 42 42 _z_. That'll give you the correct counts and won't start another i.e. the program will finish.

Comment: This section of the book made me wonder why this book comes so highly recommended: it is not well explained, it doesn't behave as they describe, and is a pedagogical nightmare all around. FWIW, I just put the following at the beginning of my program: `std::cout << "Enter space-delimited integers and a letter to finish." << std::endl;` This is basically one of Joe Z's suggestions. Not sure why you didn't accept his answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your program as-written appears correct for a series of numeric inputs separated by whitespace.

You need to give an end-of-file indication to the program so that it will exit the `while` loop and print the count for the final data.  In Windows, you can do that by entering [Ctrl]-[Z] as the first character on a new line.  In Linux, UNIX and Mac OS X, [Ctrl]-[D] serves a similar purpose.

Alternately, you can put your set of values into a text file and use redirection to feed your program.  Suppose, for example, you put your data in a file named `data.txt` in the same directory as your executable.  In a terminal window, you can run your program as follows:

```
myprogram < data.txt
```

As some others have noted, a non-numeric input will also work in place of end of file.  For example, you could enter `42 42 10 10 fred`, and it'll output what you expect as well.  That doesn't appear to be the intent of the program, though.  For example, if you input `42 42 10 10 fred 37`, the program stops at `fred` and won't see `37`.

Comment: This is a great answer and should be accepted. This section of the book is sort of awful, frankly.